# join 2 tables with multiple id for the connector in other table and get the last record by group

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have a problem with mysql query. I want to join 2 table ( such as table A and table B ):

table A :

```
ID_A   date    name
1      2014    hhh
2      2014    jjj
3      2014    kkk
```

table B :

```
ID_B   ID_A    mark
1      1       90
2      1       85
3      2       70
4      2       75
5      3       90
6      3       80
```

i want to join table A with table B, i have done it using *group by*, but the problem is i want to get last recort of each ID_A (based on ID_B) in table B.
i have did this query :

```
select * from `table A` a join `table B` b on b.ID_A=a.ID_A group by a.ID_A
```

but it no select the last record of each ID_A in table B, and also i did this query:

```
select * from `table A` a join `table B` b on (select ID_A from `table B` order by ID_B desc limit 1)=a.ID_A group by a.ID_A
```

but also failed.

i want the result like this:

```
ID_A   ID_B    mark   name
1      2       85     hhh
2      4       75     jjj
3      6       80     kkk
```

really need your help guys..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option joining the table back to itself using the `max` aggregate:

```
select a.id_a, a.name, 
  b.id_b, b.mark
from tableA a
  join tableB b on a.id_a = b.id_a
  join (
      select id_a, max(id_b) maxidb
      from tableB
      group by id_a
    ) c on b.id_a = c.id_a and b.id_b = c.maxidb
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c94f1/1)

Comment: I'd select b.id_a - but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ID_A, b.ID_B, mark, name 
FROM `table A` a JOIN `table B` b ON b.ID_A=a.ID_A
WHERE ID_B IN (SELECT MAX(ID_B) FROM `table B` GROUP BY ID_A)
GROUP BY a.ID_A
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6035/1)

Comment: what if there is date column in table B, then i change ID_B with date? i tried it but 0 rows affected. it is similar, isn't?

Comment: You mean you change column type of ID_B to date?